# using the data-custom="" to bind to events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm pretty sure I'm gonna get slammed on this.

I love using the data-whatever attribute to bind events to.

It feels very clean to me and helps reserve my class attribute for just styling.

I know this selector is among the slowest, so I don't use it when there are a lot of elements.

Would love to hear compelling arguments against this.

```
$("body").delegate("[data-action]", "click", function(){
var action = $(this).attr("data-action");

//route action to appropriate function

});
```

Comment: using `$("body").delegate()` is basically the same as using `live()` - which is deprecated.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind on an answer do you expect to get.

Comment: It sounds like you are choosing to do something which you know is inefficient. The only advice I could give is to measure the performance overhead so that you know exactly what the trade-off you are making is.

Comment: I am just asking for some peer review here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("body").delegate("[data-action]", "click", function(){
   ^^^^-------------------------- body is a too high node.
          ^^^^^^^^--------------- on should be used now instead of delegate.
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ attribute selector is a slow selector.
```

Comment: I used "body" just for the example.  I definitely try to narrow it down.  Good call on using "on" and not "delegate" I will review it in the Docs.